# Обращение к элементу, созданого динамически ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

После загрузки сайта, динамически появляется `<span class="mejs-captions-text"></span>` как к нему обратиться и извлечь данные?

Стандартные методы не работают:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("mejs-captions-text")[0];
```

undefined

```
$('.mejs-captions-text');
```

null

---

**Ответ:** Как оказалось, данный элемент, действительно, находился через фрейм, на другом домене.

Comment: Так не бывает. Эти методы обязаны его найти, если он есть на странице. Значит на странице его нет или он не с тем классом. После того как он появился на экране посмотрите текущую страницу в режиме разработчика и посмотрите как этот span там реально выглядит

Comment: Я говорю о том, что он появляется после загрузки DOM, и ищу способ как обратиться после этого к элементу

Comment: Не важно в какой момент он появился. Если он есть в DOM на момент вызова этих функций они его найдут !

Comment: Вероятно, вы ищите **до** того, как этот элемент появляется.

Comment: Делаю отладку через консоль. Во вкладке html  я вижу этот элемент, значит, он все-таки есть уже на странице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте время: что происходит раньше, а что позже.

Если раньше создаётся элемент, а позже ищется – всё в порядке. В ситуации, когда ищется раньше, чем создаётся, разумеется, ничего не обнаружит. Вот пример:

```js
function createIt() {
  $('body').append('<span class="mejs-captions-text">значение и смысл</span>');
}

function getIt() {
  var value = $('.mejs-captions-text').html();
  console.log(value);
  $('body').append('<div>Значение: ' + value + '</div>');
}

// Не работает:
// setTimeout( createIt, 2000);
// setTimeout( getIt, 1000);

// Работает:
setTimeout( createIt, 1000);
setTimeout( getIt, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Делаю отладку через консоль. Во вкладке html я вижу этот элемент, значит, он все-таки есть уже на странице

Comment: **Что раньше:** срабатывает код, пытающийся получить значение, или вы смотрите во вкладку `html`?

Comment: Алгоритм такой:
Загружается страница,
Я нажимаю на элемент на сайте который подгружает дополнительный блок,
Я вижу нужный span в html,
Далее, копирую класс,
Открываю консоль и обращаюсь к элементу,
$('.mejs-captions-text');
И возвращается null

Comment: Может, там фреймы, разные домены? Консольная команда работает в корневом документе и не имеет доступа к фреймам с других доменов? Попробуйте этот же трюк повторить здесь, выполнив сниппет в моём ответе – он выполняется во фрейме с другого домена, и, по идее, у вас будет пустой массив в ответе.

Comment: Могу ли я вам дать ссылку на ресурс, с подробной инструкцией, что я хочу сделать?

Comment: Наше с вами решение проблемы должно быть потенциально полезно другим участникам, с похожими затруднениями. Можете привести ссылку тут, отредактировав ваш вопрос.

Comment: Повторил, действительно вернулся пустой массив. Каким образом я могу извлечь из него данные ?

Comment: Разберитесь со структурой страницы – с какого домена и в какой фрейм приходит нужный элемент.